# Unity Player floating down instead of falling

Tags: unity-game-engine

for some reason my Player is reacting really weirdly to the gravity, he falls normally for about 1 second then just floats down the rest of the way really slowly. increasing the gravity doesnt change anything either. Im at a loss.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
using UnityEngine;

public class newThirdPersonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public Transform cam;
    public float speed = 6;
    public float gravity = -20f;
    public float jumpHeight = 1;
    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    float turnSmoothVelocity;
    public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()

    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2 * gravity);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
            Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
            controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MAybe it would be better to share all your script in case someone takes the chance to check your jumping approach out. Why not attach a rigidbody component and use unity's physics gravity?? That is quite an easy way

Comment: @rustyBucketBay afaik `CharacterController` basically acts like a `Rigidbody` except it is controlled fully by code instead of physics but still allows react to collisions .. it most cases it is easier to control via user Input than an actual `Rigidbody` ;)

Comment: oh, I was not aware that `CharacterController` was a unity class. Thanks for pointing that out